# OMDb API search with JQuery / JSON not working

Tags: jquery, json, api

I am learning to use API's.  I am trying to search the OMDb API for a movie title and then have the movie image / poster appear in my site.  I can not get this code to work and would appreciate knowing where I am going wrong.  Thank you in advance.

```
     // Creating the AJAX Request
//
$('form').submit(function(event) {
  // Stop the form from submitting
  event.preventDefault();

  // Get The value from the form
  var movieURL = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?";
  var movieName = $('#search').val();
  var movieOptions = {
    s: "",

  };

  function displayMovies(data) {
    var movieHTML = '<ul>';
    $.each(data.items, function(index, value) {
      movieHTML += '<li>';
      movieHTML += '<img ';
      movieHTML += 'src="' + value.Poster + '" ';
      movieHTML += 'alt="' + value.Title + '" >';
      movieHTML += '</li>';
    });//end each
    movieHTML += '</ul>';
    $('movieInformation').html(movieHTML);

  }
  $.getJSON(movieURL, movieOptions, displayMovies);// end getJSON

}); // end submit function



  <div class="heading">
        <h1>Movie Search</h1>
        <form>
          <label for="search">Type a movie title</label>
          <input type="search" name="search" id="search">
          <input type="submit" value="Search" id="submit">
        </form>

      </div>



    <div id="movieInformation">
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about the issue. Are there any errors in the browser console.

Comment: Hello, I do not have any errors showing in the console.  So am thinking I am missing something when requesting the information. I opened the network setting and can not see any information when I click on submit.  I am wondering if // Get The value from the form
  var movieURL = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?";
  var movieName = $('#search').val();
  var movieOptions = {
    s: "",

  };    is correct, or if I need another variable to store the search request in?

Comment: Can you provide a snippet or a fiddle.

Comment: Why have you written the function `displayMovies` within the submit handler.

Comment: Hello, The course I did showed me this approach using API's, this is why I have followed this syntax.  Any advice is appreciated. 
 https://jsfiddle.net/wrfpw961/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things I noticed:

`movieURL` is not a properly constructed URL according to the API. The request you're sending does not include the search value. You have:

`"http://www.omdbapi.com/?"` instead of:

`"https://www.omdbapi.com/?t="+movieName`

The response is an object, and does not contain a 'items` property:

`$.each(data.items, function(index, value) {`

I've created a fiddle which logs the content of your response `data`. You'll see exactly which properties you have access to.

https://jsfiddle.net/um69o5t3/1/

Update:

Here's what I changed:

```js
$('form').submit(function(event) {
  // Stop the form from submitting
  event.preventDefault();

  // Get The value from the form
  var movieName = $('#search').val();
  var movieURL = "https://www.omdbapi.com/?t="+movieName;

  var movieOptions = {
    s: "",

  };

  function displayMovies(data) {
  console.log(data);
   /* var movieHTML = '<ul>';
    $.each(data.items, function(index, value) {
      movieHTML += '<li>';
      movieHTML += '<img ';
      movieHTML += 'src="' + value.Poster + '" ';
      movieHTML += 'alt="' + value.Title + '" >';
      movieHTML += '</li>';
    });//end each*/
    console.log(data.Title);
        var movieHTML = '<ul>';
      movieHTML += '<li>';
      movieHTML += '<img ';
      movieHTML += 'src="' + data.Poster + '" ';
      movieHTML += 'alt="' + data.Title + '" >';
      movieHTML += '</li>';
    
    movieHTML += '</ul>';
    $('#movieInformation').html(movieHTML);

  }
  $.getJSON(movieURL, movieOptions, displayMovies);// end getJSON

}); // end submit function
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="heading">
        <h1>Movie Search</h1>
        <form>
          <label for="search">Type a movie title</label>
          <input type="search" name="search" id="search">
          <input type="submit" value="Search" id="submit">
        </form>

      </div>



    <div id="movieInformation">
    </div>
```

Comment: Good luck, I'm happy to help if you run into issues.

Comment: Thank you Tony M.  That is exactly what I couldn't work out!  If you see this could you please tell me where you saw the correct endpoint to use        var movieURL = "https://www.omdbapi.com/?t=";  so I know how to look more effectively in the future?

Comment: Np! Typically, an API that requires you to send a search query will accept those search queries via the url (query params). The documentation https://www.omdbapi.com/ has a section "Parameters" which shows you all sorts of search parameters available - title is one of them. The examples section also shows you a properly constructed URL. As a rule of thumb, if you're sending info (e.g movie title) to an endpoint and you can't point out where that information being sent from, something is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Answer has been accepted.